# Unable to mint from any wallet on Solana/metaplex candymachine V2

Tags: web, solana, nft, metaplex

hey guys i basically created a solana nft using hashlips and metaplex on the mainnet but when i go to the minting website i am only able to mint on the owners wallet, any other wallet just doesnt work.

i have already checked the .env file and the date is set back by 2 days.

[www.notdegentoonz.io](http://www.notdegentoonz.io)   this is the website so you can check and see what i mean.

[this is on the owners wallet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jr2RK.png)

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Rather, it is about minting NFTs.

Answer (score 1):

There was a successful mint recently from a wallet thats not the authority:

https://solscan.io/tx/5Mx8zvnFpmMAXZVwLNSyBwzFU6nQwDJUqqkFG8qBYLU3Ewe57fWDfoCJ3rYuxiuFjDdQdc85d6rCqu7nngZvJAMB

Looks like there is no issue or you already fixed it.

The only thing that I saw on chain which might have been missing is

> Program log: Missing set collection during mint IX for Candy Machine with collection set, Candy Machine Botting is taxed at 10000000 lamports

which would say that your UI is outdated. In that case the recommendation is to update to a website which includes set set collection IX like the current candy-machine-ui

Comment: Hey. If you haven't already done so, please commit to the Solana Stackexchange. area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126615/solana You could greatly help us reach our goal!